# A question on the formula in calculating the standard score

Tags: statistics

We all know that the formula for calculating z, the standard score, from the raw data x is given by

z(i) = [x(i) – μ]/σ

{Some use ‘bar x’ instead of μ but μ is much easier to type and this is not the point of my question.}

My questions are:-

--(1) Who sets up this standard?

--(2) Why this setup logic is generally accepted?

--(3) x is linearly transformed to z but why the transformation constants are artificially chosen to be (1/σ) and (-μ/σ)?

--(4) The numerator part is easy to understand. The denominator part?

Comment: If $X$ is normal mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, then $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is standard normal.

Answer (score 1):

The normal distribution is described mostly in terms of how far you are, in terms of standard deviations, from the mean. This is precisely what the $z-$ value measures: you subtract a value from the population mean ( which is known in this case), and then you divide by $\sigma$. This tells you the distance of your chosen value in terms of standard deviations from the mean.

The reason for the transform constants is to transform  a normal distribution  $N(\mu, \sigma)$ into the canonical "standard normal" with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$, which is the canonical and best understood distribution .

Comment: Explanation is reasonable enough.